# Angular routing to nested modules

Tags: angular

I Have three modules each with a routing module

```
app.module
layout.module
project.module
```

The layout module contains my header, footer and sidebar. I then want my project module to load inside of the layouts module.

What I am getting is the layouts module loading fine at the root url, this is using the app.component router-outlet. But if I link to one of the child components of the project component it seems to bypass the router-outlet inside of the layout.component and loads without any of the headers and footers.

#### app.component.html

```
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

#### app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

// Modules
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { LayoutModule } from './layout/layout.module';

// Services
import { AppService } from './services/app.service';

// Components
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    LayoutModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    AppService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

#### app-routing.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes: Routes = [

  { path: '', loadChildren: './layout/layout.module#LayoutModule' },

  { path: '', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  providers: [

  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

#### layout.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { ProjectModule } from '../project/project.module';
import { LayoutRoutingModule } from './layout-routing.module';

import { LayoutComponent } from './layout/layout.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    NgbModule,
    ProjectModule,
    LayoutRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    LayoutComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    LayoutComponent
  ],
  providers: [
  ]
})
export class LayoutModule { }
```

#### layout-routing.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LayoutComponent } from './layout/layout.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: LayoutComponent, children: [
      { path: 'project', loadChildren: '../project/project.module#ProjectModule' },
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LayoutRoutingModule { }
```

#### layout.component.html

```
  <div class="layout-content">
    <div>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I then have a project module and project-routing module which should load the projects.component, in that component will be the children components for this.

#### project-routing.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { ProjectComponent } from './project.component';
import { ProjectWizardComponent } from './project-wizard/project-wizard.component';
import { ViewerComponent } from './viewer/viewer.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'projects',
    component: ProjectComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'wizard',
        component: ProjectWizardComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'view',
        component: ViewerComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: []
})
export class ProjectRoutingModule { }
```